# Как в телеграм боте сделать функцию input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Использую библиотеку PyTelegramBotApi
Хочу сделать телеграмм бот-калькулятора. Который бы принимал любое число введенное пользователям и выполнял команду. Не могу придумать код. Кто сможет помочь, как реализовать функцию `input` в телеграм боте?

Отрывок с кода. По задумке человек должен вести число, и нажать на стрелку вперед, а бот должен сохранить это число. Так пользователь водит два числа, воспользовавшись стрелкой, а программа должна их прибавить. Не могу придумать код что бы реализовать это.

```
elif call.data == 'pravo':
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=True,
                              text="Введи свої бали ЗНО, шляхом натискання кнопки ➡️") 
    keybord3 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="➡", callback_data="zno1")
    keybord3.add(button)
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, 
                          message_id=call.message.message_id, 
                          text="Введіть Бали ЗНО з українскьої мови", 
                          reply_markup=keybord3)
```

Comment: В чём конкретно проблема? Приведите ваш код

Comment: И какую библиотеку используете? Если это `python-telegram-bot`, то в ней для сохранения данных можно использовать удобное встроенное хранилище `context.user_data` ([пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c4cbe75c6fc2c818c01090eb5921ecee9d878dd6/telegram_bot_examples/user_data__PicklePersistence/main.py#L41))

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Answer (score 1):

Вот уже готовая реализация калькулятора. Единственное - в боте реализовано только сложение (+). В роли input() тут выступает функция bot.register_next_step_handler. Также реализовал а-ля Key-Value хранилище в памяти

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('BOT TOKEN HERE')
storage = {}

def init_storage(user_id):
  storage[user_id] = dict(first_number=None, second_number=None)

def store_number(user_id, key, value):
  storage[user_id][key] = dict(value=value)

def get_number(user_id, key):
  return storage[user_id][key].get('value')

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def start(message):
  init_storage(message.from_user.id)
  bot.reply_to(message, "Введите + чтобы прибавить два числа ")
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, plus)

def plus(message):
      if message.text == "+":
         bot.reply_to(message,"Enter number 1: ")
         bot.register_next_step_handler(message, plus_one)
      else:
         bot.reply_to(message, "Введите + чтобы прибавить два числа ")
         bot.register_next_step_handler(message, plus)

def plus_one(message):
        first_number = message.text

        if not first_number.isdigit():
            msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Enter only digits!')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, plus_one)
            return

        store_number(message.from_user.id, "first_number", first_number)
        bot.reply_to(message, "Enter number 2: ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, plus_two)

def plus_two(message):
       second_number = message.text

       if not second_number.isdigit():
            msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Enter only digits!')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, plus_two)
            return

       store_number(message.from_user.id, "second_number", second_number)

       number_1 = get_number(message.from_user.id, "first_number")
       number_2 = get_number(message.from_user.id, "second_number")

       result_plus = int(number_1) + int(number_2)
       bot.reply_to(message, f"Ответ: {result_plus}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.skip_pending = True
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    #bot.infinity_polling()
```

[image: Сриншот работы бота]

Удачи!